# Threading issue with running WatiN tests under VSTestHost

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing, tfs, watin, vstesthost

I've gotten a simple WatiN web test running on my dev environment and am trying to get it working on the TFS build server. WatiN is firing an exception:

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException: The CurrentThread needs to have it's 
ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.
```

The test runner, VSTestHost supposedly uses STA threading by default. I've also tried explicitly forcing it to STA via the .testrunconfig file. Still WatiN is unhappy.
I'm using Visual Studio/TFS 2008 on Windows Server 2008.

Has anyone else hit this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check/use `[STAThread]` attribute for your WatiN test methods

Answer (score 0):

Editing the testrunconfig as you suggest should be the solution. What syntax did you try? as far as I can recall for 2008 it's

```
 <ExecutionThread apartmentState="1" />
```

and for 2005 it's

```
<apartmentState type="System.Threading.ApartmentState">
  <value__ type="System.Int32">1</value__>
</apartmentState>
```

Comment: I used, <ExecutionThread apartmentState="STA" /> which should be valid, but redundant.
See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/a7b31008-457a-49bb-baa0-815cec38a8ed

Comment: The ="1" syntax is not valid according to this blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/irenak/archive/2008/02/22/sysk-365-how-to-get-your-unit-tests-test-project-in-visual-studio-2008-a-k-a-mstest-run-multithreaded.aspx